# Customizing SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Is it possible to customize SimpleMembershipProvider in the sense of requiring more than just a user name and password for login?

For example, suppose I want 4 pieces of information:

```
Login, Password, Abc, Xyz
(Abc and Xyz are just generic placeholders, for now)

Suppose your login is: 

john/mypassword555/1/1 (authenticated) -> pagex
john/mypassword999/1/2 (authenticated) -> pagey

bob/mypassword333/1/1 (authenticated) -> pagex
bob/mypassword333/1/2 (authenticated) ->pagey
bob/mypassword333/1/3 (authenticated) -> pagez
```

Having just john/mypassword or bob/mypassword333 would be insufficient.

I want to be able to have either the same password for all logins or different passwords, but still require all 4 fields before Request.IsAuthenticated is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but:

If you need data A, B, and C plus a password to log in, you could store A, B, and C into an object structure, serialize that object to a string, and pass that string to your custom membership provider as "login" along with the password, which would then deserialize the object back to its parts. At that point you can do whatever you want in your custom provider.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would mean that the login (from a high level overview) would be something like john11 (for john/1/1) and john12 (for john/1/2) so even though the textbox login is "john" the membership provider would treat the member string as the serialized entry johnABDEAWHATEVER..... is that what you are saying? If so, I believe that may work....

Comment: That's a pretty dirty solution and breaks the integrity of the provider interface. The provider model is designed so it can be swaped out with any implementation and without requiring an update to the code. This would break that, it's better to implement the business logic in the application and use the lower-level provider APIs for username/password as it's designed after passing the other checks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to just use the built-in membership provider and once they log in, take them to another page where they would enter the additional information.

When they enter the additional information, you can then set a Session/Cookie that you would check using a custom Authorization filter.

This way you can ensure that all 4 fields have been provided before Request.IsAuthenticated evaluates to true.

Comment: This is not what I mean. As I said, You cannot log in, and then require the additional information, as suppose there is a user named "john" who has a password of "password" but the other 2 bits of required information are "x" and "y". Now another user, "john", who also by coincidence picks the same password "password" (rare, but could happen), would get logged in. Without requiring the other 2 bits of information, I don't want IsAuthenticated to be true yet.